# Почему не может найти путь к tesseract?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Указываю путь с папкой, где лежит tesseract v5, но он пытается найти его в Program Files x86
Ошиибка в консоли:
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\rus.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'rus' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')

Все библиотеки с языками в моей папке есть

Comment: Ну ошибка же английским по белому пишет, что нужно установить переменную `TESSDATA_PREFIX`

Comment: @strawdog а как это сделать? до этого у меня все работало, ничего дополнительно не устанавливал. Прописал в Path C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\, не помогло

Comment: ну, судя по ошибке, надо не прописывать в path, а создать переменную окружения TESSDATA_PREFIX, куда и прописать C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\